# SKPhysics body no collision detection

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am trying to create a circle that falls and then stops at the bottom of the screen, but the circle instead just keeps falling. Any ideas?

I've updated the code to show the updated bit masks:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = EDGE_BIT_MASK;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = BUBBLE_BIT_MASK | BALL_BIT_MASK;
self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;

self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

growingNode = [SKShapeNode node];
growingNode.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y, 100, 100)].CGPath;
growingNode.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
growingNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:growingNode.frame.size.width / 2];
growingNode.physicsBody.dynamic = true;
growingNode.physicsBody.restitution = 0.2;
growingNode.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
growingNode.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
growingNode.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
growingNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = EDGE_BIT_MASK | BALL_BIT_MASK;
growingNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BUBBLE_BIT_MASK;
growingNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BALL_BIT_MASK;
growingNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
growingNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
growingNode.physicsBody.mass = growingNode.frame.size.width / self.frame.size.width;


[self addChild:growingNode];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the collision bitmask values of the edge and bubble nodes accordingly:

```
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = BUBBLE_BIT_MASK;

growingNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = BALL_BIT_MASK | EDGE_BIT_MASK;
```

Comment: I tried that. When I set each of the collisionBitMask's, the growing node is no longer affected by gravity.

Comment: Could you post the code where you have set the bitmask values?

Comment: I've updated the code above to show the updated bit mask values.

Comment: I mean what values have you set for these bitmasks? I am talking about the enum